# mysql WP custom query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

this code is designed to select posts with selected meta value in wordpress query

```
<?php $values = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key  = 'wpcf-scr'",ARRAY_A);?>
<select name="wpcf-scr">
<option value="">default</option>
<?php foreach ($values as $value):?>
<?php if($value['meta_value']):?>
    <option value="<?php echo $value['meta_value']?>"><?php echo $value['meta_value']?></option>
<?php endif;?>
<?php endforeach;?>
</select>
```

I need to re use the code but with selecting posts with tags(manual assigned) not meta values...

something like this below just for explanation (it's wrong)

```
<?php $values = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT post_tags FROM $wpdb->tags ",ARRAY_A);?>
<select name="tags">
<option value="">default</option>
<option value="tag1">tag1</option>
<option value="tag1">tag2</option>
<option value="tag1">tag3</option>
<option value="tag1">tag4</option>
</select>
```

How to make the second example correctly ?

thanks

Comment: You are not selecting posts but post-tags in your second example. Your answer: Yes, it could happen – you just need to know a little about SQL queries or come up with a specific question on what is your problem…

Comment: ok, my question is: how to make the second example but in correct way? because i'am a designer and don't know about SQL queries.. thanks

Comment: Try learning a little SQL and see if you can figure it out: http://www.sql-tutorial.net/. If you have specific questions, don't be afraid to ask!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the wp function to get the tags.. get_tags()
and then iterate the loop..